# How to merge staging data in a specific order when the target table has foreign keys

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to modularize the merging of staging data for our branches.

Currently, I get an export file (zip) from our system supplier once per day per branch (50+ branches). Via a series of Azure functions, I extract the zip, which gives a series of tsv files, I then upload each tsv file to a staging table. After making the required transformations to the staging data, I need to merge the staging data into the correct table.

I have written separate stored procedures to handle the merging of each table. I know a staging table is ready to be merged once the function that handles the data transformations writes a message to an Azure queue to alert to this. This message is then used by a final function to trigger the specific stored procedure.

The issue I have is many of the target tables have foreign keys.

As an example one table (TransferLine) lists the items for branch transfers, this includes the TransferID field which is the ID of a transfer in the TransferHeader table. As I have FK's set up, in this instance, the TransferID must exist in the TransferHeader table, so the TransferHeader staging table data needs to be processed before the TransferLines staging table as a new TransferId would not be present.

TransferHeader table (extraneous columns ignored)

```
TransferId varchar(15) PK
TransferType int NOT NULL
...
```

TransferLine table (extraneous columns ignored) You can see the TransferId is part of a composite key with ProductId.

```
TransferId varchar(15) PK FK
ProductId varchar(35) PK
ProductCode varchar(20) NOT NULL
TransferQuantity int NOT NULL
...
```

Is there a correct way to decide whether to run immediately or delay the run of a stored procedure?

Is this setup so far even a viable solution, or am I going about this the wrong way? From what I have read, delays and waits inside SQL Server are based on timers or commands. As I can't guarantee whether the e.g. TransferHeader or TransferLine staging data is stored first, I don't believe direct SQL Server solutions are best in my case.

I understand I could have a trigger that could fire when all tables are handled and then run each stored procedure in a desired order. The reason I am wanting to modularize it is to handle each table as its own. In extreme circumstances, a branch may create no new transfers for a day but may edit an existing one. This would mean there would be no TransferHeader tsv file for that day but a TransferLine one would be there. That way I can't simply wait for the TransferHeader table to process as it would be skipped that day.

Lastly, I should add, I can transform the data once I have it but I am required to start with the data as is presented by the system supplier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to conceptualize your setup. Seeing the code of the process and stored procedures would probably be helpful.

But it sounds like your issue is the fact that your header and lines tables' processes could be running in parallel, with the chance of the lines table being updated first, essentially. If so, then you basically need to remove the parallel part of the process and explicitly update the lines sequentially after the headers process is complete.

One way to do that, is to have a procedure for each set of related tables. In your example there's only two tables in the dependency chain, which makes this simple. If there were more tables introduced with more foreign keys to a mix of the other tables, it could make this more complex.

So for example, I'd have a `ProcessTranfers` procedure that handles the `TransferHeader` table first and then the `TransferLines` second, since that's the order of the dependencies by the foreign keys.

> The reason I am wanting to modularize it is to handle each table as its own. In extreme circumstances, a branch may create no new transfers for a day but may edit an existing one. This would mean there would be no TransferHeader tsv file for that day but a TransferLine one would be there. That way I can't simply wait for the TransferHeader table to process as it would be skipped that day.

In such a scenario, with my aforementioned approach, there would be no work for the first part of the `ProcessTransfers` procedure for the `TransferHeader` table, and it would immediately do only the work needed for the `TransferLine` table.

> Is this setup so far even a viable solution, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Smells slightly like it's the wrong path. The purpose of a foreign key is to enforce a constraint that the parent record exists in order for the children records to exist (simplified definition). If your current process can't guarantee that order of events, then it potentially violates that foreign key constraint. Your options are to either design a process that guarantees the proper order of events, or to remove the foreign key constraint and have intermittent risk of there being child rows without a parent, for a period of time.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right. I did simplify the relations in the question, the line table has 4 Foreign Keys. I will stick with the simple solution of processing all the data in a modular format but for the merge, I will create an SP specifically to merge the staging data in the desired order.

Comment: @Colin-G-Davidson Np! You may find it better organized by having a separate procedure for the Header, and separate procedure for the Lines, and then the parent generic procedure called `ProcessTransfers` that executes those child procedures in the correct order. That way the code is more readable and still modular (if you had any special cases). But the usual case will be calling `ProcessTransfers` to handle everything for you. (A smart guy I know suggested this.)